# Bash script vs. writing C program to call other programs

Tags: c, bash, fork

I have 3-5 (large-ish) programs that I need merge so that they run sequentially. Speed is important, since this is for (near) real-time applications. (If there is a better way, let me know).

Would it make more sense to write a Bash script to call these other programs or to write a C program that will most likely use `fork()` and/or `exec()`? Are the trade-offs between speed and difficulty/time spent coding in favor of one over the other? Are there other methods I should look into?

I apologize if my terminology is off or if there is not enough information. Also, please correct me so that I do not repeat the same mistakes in the future.

Comment: The term "real time" is generally reserved for systems that need [microsecond level guarantees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing) regarding scheduling. Things like web servers and video chat are not considered real time.

Comment: @thatotherguy ...well, video chat _can_ be real-time if you're making promises about framerate (and particularly if you don't have adequate hardware buffering, and need to read content out of a memory-mapped region before it's overwritten). If it's just best-effort, not so much.

Comment: Real time merely means "on time". Meaning that something must finish/deliver before a given time period has ended. If your system is guaranteed to always deliver "on time", then it is a real time system. Anything relying on TCP/IP or the internet is not a real time system, because there are no guarantees when the packages will arrive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the perfect use case for bash. The overhead will be less than a millisecond, and maintenance cost is way lower than for a C program.

Answer (score 2):

The question posed is a classic question of **"what is the correct tool for the job?"**. Obviously, bash being a shell is designed to launch applications, scripting the launch of multiple programs is as simple as listing the programs you need on separate lines along with the required arguments. But when the question is one of speed, it is one you can only answer by asking **"How fast is fast enough?"**

If you currently have separate programs you can string together and they can complete the job in an acceptable amount of time, why would you ever think about re-writing them for speed? The fact that you are asking the questions shows, you are either (a) having difficulty with the time it takes for the current routines to complete, of (b) you just want to see how much faster you can make it go. We all like hot-rods right?

Are there speed advantages to be had re-writing large shell apps that are number intensive in a compiled language like C -- you bet. Many times by hundreds of percent, but is it worth the time it takes to re-write. That's something only you can answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest writing the bash script and debugging it.  If the performance proves adequate, you are done.  It is reasonable to expect `bash` on a modern system (hardware and kernel) to perform well.

Otherwise use the bash script as the specification for writing a replacement C program.

Comment: +1 for the empirical approach - you don't know until you try.